# How to store login state in a VSCODE extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm developing a Visual Studio Code extension and trying to create my own Authentication Provider.
Now I can sign in successfully and create the session.
I'm wondering how to store the login state so that I can control the functionality of my extension, such as controlling the display or hiding of specific features or interfaces.
Should I use something like
`vscode.commands.executeCommand('setContext', 'loggedIn', true)`
or workspaceState and globalState. What’s the best prcatice?
Thanks in advance.

I want to control the extension's interface and functionality based on the login status

Comment: you have to use `when` clauses for your GUI stuff if you want it to be controlled by login status, if you write your View completely yourself, `WebviewView`, than context is not needed

Comment: best to prefix context variables with the extension name: `myExtName.loggedIn`

Comment: Ok，so I can use `when` clauses to enable/disable GUI. But if Vs code or the extension is restarted, will the context disappear?

Comment: yes, it is the same as closing VSC and open it again, all the old state/context is gone, or you have to store on modify and retrieve on start (activate) from persistent storage in `extension.context` (argument of `activate`)

Comment: Does VS Code have an appropriate method to store this information？Login status, username, permissions, etc.

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#ExtensionContext